# Golang mgo result into simple slice

Tags: mongodb, go, unmarshalling, mgo

I'm fairly new to both Go and MongoDB. Trying to select a single field from the DB and save it in an int slice without any avail.

```
userIDs := []int64{}

coll.Find(bson.M{"isdeleted": false}).Select(bson.M{"userid": 1}).All(&userIDs)
```

The above prints out an empty slice. However, if I create a struct with a single `ID` field that is int64 with marshalling then it works fine.

All I am trying to do is work with a simple slice containing IDs that I need instead of a struct with a single field. All help is appreciated.

Comment: can you do it with native mongodb client? you may not support a db client to do much helper functions. but you can do it with a simple function to convert a []struct to []int64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because mgo queries return documents, a few lines of code is required to accomplish the goal:

```
var result []struct{ UserID int64 `bson:"userid"` }
err := coll.Find(bson.M{"isdeleted": false}).Select(bson.M{"userid": 1}).All(&result)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
userIDs := make([]int64, len(result))
for i := range result {
    userIDs[i] = result.UserID
}
```

Comment: That is what I ended up using. Was just feeling weird writing that conversion and wanted to see if there was another way. Thanks